# What folders can be deleted from create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs

I want to put my first react app on my website but the file size is 122MB. What folders can be deleted from node_modules?

Comment: Folders should never be deleted from `node_modules/`. You should treat it as a black box that's managed by yarn/npm. You should run `npm install` or `yarn` on your server if you need packages. Never manually copy a `node_modules` folder to another place. For create-react-app, there's deploy documentation https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment

Answer (score 4):

Run [npm run build](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-build) and deploy folders `build` and `public` only. Those contain all you need for production.